# Cookie is Empty in Wordpress Add Action with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, action

I am trying to access a cookie within a Wordpress action.  The action registration is below and it works with static data.  But when I try to access a cookie, a cookie I know works because I have echoed it on the page, is always empty.  Does this action have access to the $_COOKIE object?  If not what solution can I do?

```
add_action ('comment_post', array(&$cisco_rewards, 'add_comment_badge_id'), 1);

function add_comment_badge_id($comment_id) {

        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'badge_id', $_COOKIE[Cisco_Rewards::REWARDS_COOKIE_NAME], true); // I put just a 2 here and it worked correctly, blank otherwise with the cookie.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` is a [superglobal variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) so it is available inside any object (or any scope), so that can't be the problem. A couple of thoughts:

Have you tried to print `$_COOKIE` just before you pass it to `add_comment_meta()` so you can check the keys and values? Like:

```
function add_comment_badge_id($comment_id)
{
    exit(print_r($_COOKIE));
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'badge_id', $_COOKIE[Cisco_Rewards::REWARDS_COOKIE_NAME], true);
}
```

Check that you are [setting the cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) with the same domain name with which you are doing the tests. Perhaps you are setting it with **www.domain.com** and you are accessing the page with **http://domain.com** ?

Note as well that you set the cookie on a request and it is available in the next one ([see this brief but well explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605402/cookie-seems-to-not-reflect-change-after-setting-it) here in SO).

Comment: Yep, cookie not even in there.  Didn't know about EXIT in php (.NET developer here).  Main problem was not setting path=/ on cookie and having it at the end in javascript.